# Move all sockets from array to specific room

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So, let's say I have an array of few socket ids (['RZ0_7yBdwyvlT8-bAAAA', 'iyeiRpVdmzAQSWyTAAAB', 'kSd2Iudt9SV29w9HAAAC']). On particular trigger, i want to move everyone from array to one socket.io room so i can emit events only to them. How can I do that??

Comment: Please show what you have tried so we can help sort out your specific problem? What research have you done on this? Asking questions here shouldn't be first point of research

Answer (score 2):

You first need to get socket object from socketId and then call `join("room_name")` on it.

Let say room name is `random`.

```
var room_name = "random";
var ids = ['RZ0_7yBdwyvlT8-bAAAA', 'iyeiRpVdmzAQSWyTAAAB', 'kSd2Iudt9SV29w9HAAAC'];
ids.forEach(function(){
     io.sockets.connected[id].join(room_name); // for v1.0
     // io.sockets.sockets[id].join(room_name); // for V0.9
});
```